# QGIS: How to report test failure?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to build QGIS from sources.
I run the `ctest` command at the end, which gives me such results (master branch):

```
91% tests passed, 45 tests failed out of 490

Total Test time (real) = 1364.33 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      7 - ProcessingQgisAlgorithmsTest (Failed)
      8 - ProcessingGdalAlgorithmsTest (Failed)
      9 - ProcessingGrass7AlgorithmsImageryTest (Failed)
     10 - ProcessingGrass7AlgorithmsRasterTest (Failed)
     11 - ProcessingGrass7AlgorithmsVectorTest (Failed)
     12 - ProcessingOtbAlgorithmsTest (Failed)
     13 - ProcessingSagaAlgorithmsTest (Failed)
     31 - qgis_coordinatereferencesystemtest (Failed)
     39 - qgis_distanceareatest (Failed)
     44 - qgis_expressiontest (Failed)
     55 - qgis_geonodeconnectiontest (Failed)
     75 - qgis_layoutmaptest (Failed)
     82 - qgis_layoutpicturetest (Failed)
     86 - qgis_layouttabletest (Failed)
    109 - qgis_ogrutilstest (Failed)
    127 - qgis_rasterlayertest (Child aborted)
    144 - qgis_taskmanagertest (Child aborted)
    155 - qgis_ziplayertest (Failed)
    192 - qgis_valuerelationwidgetwrapper (Failed)
    202 - qgis_alignrastertest (Failed)
    207 - qgis_wcsprovidertest (Failed)
    217 - qgis_qgisapp (Child aborted)
    225 - qgis_maptoolidentifyaction (Child aborted)
    248 - PyQgsAnnotation (Failed)
    275 - PyQgsDistanceArea (Failed)
    278 - PyQgsEllipsoidUtils (Failed)
    310 - PyQgsImageCache (Failed)
    320 - PyQgsLayoutAtlas (Failed)
    322 - PyQgsLayoutExporter (Failed)
    335 - PyQgsLayoutLegend (Failed)
    374 - PyQgsOGRProviderGpkg (Failed)
    388 - PyQgsPostgresDomain (Failed)
    399 - PyQgsRasterFileWriter (Failed)
    413 - PyQgsScaleWidget (Failed)
    416 - PyQgsSvgCache (Failed)
    418 - PyQgsTabfileProvider (Failed)
    428 - PyQgsSpatialiteProvider (Failed)
    441 - PyQgsSymbol (Failed)
    443 - PyQgsTaskManager (Failed)
    450 - PyQgsVectorFileWriter (Failed)
    456 - PyQgsVectorLayerUtils (Failed)
    458 - PyQgsVirtualLayerProvider (Failed)
    463 - PyQgsWFSProviderGUI (Failed)
    465 - PyQgsLayerDependencies (Failed)
    468 - PyQgsDBManagerSpatialite (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
```

I wonder where and how to report these or how to get some information, for example whether or not these failures are of concern?

Comment: I would recommend the developer mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer